# When using iterdescendants() on an etree, is it ok to modify the tree?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, python-3.x, lxml

(Python 3.2)

I'm using `etree` to parse some XML. To do this, I'm recursively iterating through the document with `iterdescendants()`. So, something like:

```
for elem in doc.iterdescendants():
    if elem.tag == "tag":
        pass # Further processing
```

Sometimes, I process a parent tag that contains children that I want to prevent from being processed in a later recursion. Is it ok to destroy the children?

In my initial testing, I've tried:

```
for child in elem.getchildren(): child.clear()
```

For some reason, this results in the element immediately after `elem` from being processed. It's like the element gets removed as well.

I then tried this, which works (in that it removes the parent and its children, but doesn't result in any subsequent siblings of the parent from being skipped/affected as well):

```
elem.clear()
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks,

Comment: I believe the behavior is undefined if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following code in place of yours and it seems to work, deleting all the child elements.  I use iterfind to find all descendants with the tag and delete them.

```
for element in doc.iterfind('.//%s'%tag):
    element.getparent().remove(element)
```

Comment: I also believe I've figured out why this works (and my other approaches didn't). In the description for `iterparse` and `iterwalk`, the documentation for lxml describes that you can modify a tree you are iterating through after the `end` event. Events only apply to iterparse and iterwalk, but I think that it applies here as well. If you are currently iterating over an element, you shouldn't touch it. But, you are free to modify its children

Comment: An alternative would probably be using doc.xpath('.//%s'%tag) to get a list of items you want to delete.